# Graphing derivatives of non-function equations

Tags: functions, derivatives

Is it possible to graph the derivatives of equations that fail the vertical line test? Such as a circle, a folium of descartes, an asteroid, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it's a little trickier, because you need to figure out the exact point on the curve. For example, if the curve is $$x^2+y^2=1,$$ the unit circle, differentiating both sides with respect to $x$ gives you $$2x + 2y\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$ which gives you $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-x}y.$$ Note that the derivatively depends on both $x$ and $y$, because there is more than one point for any $x$, and the slope is different at each point.

Graphing this derivative is a little more complicated - for any $x$ you'd have to compute the list of $y$s and compute the derivate above. This amonts to graphing $$\frac{\pm x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$ for each $x$ in the case of the circle.